# Sorting keys of array values by preserving another array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I need to compare the values of array from another array. Something I did, but I do not know how to preserve keys.

```
$razeni=Array(0=>1,1=>2,2=>0,3=>3);
$myservices=Array(0=>"text0", 1=>"text1", 2=>"text2", 3=>"text3", 4=>"text4", 5=>"text5", 6=>"text6", 7=>"text7");
```

Now compare

```
foreach ($razeni as $key=>$value) {
  $myservices_[$value] = $myservices[$value];
  unset($myservices[$value]);    
}

if (isset($myservices_))
{
  $myservices = array_merge($myservices_, $myservices);
}
```

and result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => text1
    [1] => text2
    [2] => text0
    [3] => text3
    [4] => text4
    [5] => text5
    [6] => text6
    [7] => text7
)
```

But I needed this result

```
Array
(
    [1] => text1
    [2] => text2
    [0] => text0
    [3] => text3
    [4] => text4
    [5] => text5
    [6] => text6
    [7] => text7
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using array_merge [use](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$myservices = $myservices_ + $myservices;
```

> If you want to append array elements
>   from the second array to the first
>   array while not overwriting the
>   elements from the first array and not
>   re-indexing, use the + array union
>   operator.